# Rails prefixing inserts and updates on TEXT columns with 3 dashes

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out why Rails 4 is prefixing all inserts and updates on MySQL `TEXT` fields with `---`. Everything is working, but I am just curious why it is there.

The data is a simple JSON string. Nothing special about it.

This is the ruby code that updates the database:

```
data = {'branches' => [], 'tags' => []}
//
// Some code here to populate data['branches'] and data['tags']
//
component = Component.find(params[:id])
component.available_tags = data.to_json
component.save
```

`puts data.to_json` produces following output:

```
{"branches":["develop","master","release-2014-12-15"],"tags":["release-2014-12-11","release-2014-12-10","release-2014-11-24.01","release-2014-11-24","release-2014-10-22","release-2014-10-09"]}
```

But for some reason this results in following `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE `components` SET `available_tags` = '--- \'{\"branches\":[\"develop\",\"master\",\"release-2014-12-15\"],\"tags\":[\"release-2014-12-11\",\"release-2014-12-10\",\"release-2014-11-24.01\",\"release-2014-11-24\",\"release-2014-10-22\",\"release-2014-10-09\"]}\'\n', `updated_at` = '2014-12-26 17:28:11' WHERE `components`.`id` = 10
```

I have another table with a `TEXT` field, and it also gets `---`

Here is what the table looks like:

```
mysql> desc components;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| component_name | varchar(255) | YES  |     |         |                |
| repo_url       | varchar(255) | YES  |     |         |                |
| available_tags | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| repo_type      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Are you using `available_tags` as a non-string type? Like a `Hash`? Probably so. That's why the text is sorted that way.

Comment: @Humza: Ah. That would explain it. Thank you. Would you add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the object gets `serialized` using [YAML](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) format  before being saved to the DB. If you just want to store plain text, use this:

```
component.available_tags = data.to_json.to_s
```

But, if you just want to store JSON in that column, you can add this to your model:

```
serialize :available_tags, JSON
```

This way, your `:available_tags` column will be automatically serialized/deserialized, so you don't need to run `JSON.parse` or `data.to_json` to access that field directly as a JSON object.

For example:

```
component = Component.first
component.available_tags = data # no need to use to_json, will automatically be converted
component.save
```

And

```
component = Component.first
json_object = component.available_tags  # Will return a JSON object
```

Comment: Thank you. Even though @Humza was first one to answer to question "why", you answer is more complete. I actually had `serialize :available_tags`, but it was missing the `, JSON` part. Everything works as expected now.

Comment: Yep, if you use `serialize :available_tags`, Rails will use by default `YAML` format for serialization